# How to make one of the array of the structure to the null location?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have a structure contains an array of 5 elements. I want to make one element of the array point to the `null` location.

Note: my intention is not to make any member of the structure to be assigned with zero (whether it is zero or garbage value is fine). but how can I make one member of the array of the structure point to the `null` location?

For example:

```
typedef struct    
{    
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
} alpha;

alpha abc[5];
```

I want `abc[0]` to point to the `null` location.

Comment: You would need something like `alpha *abc[5]` and then, for instance, `abc[3] = null;`

Comment: An array is not a pointer.

Comment: `alpha` is not a pointer. , so it can not "point" to the null location.

Answer (score 4):

Null values are only allowed to pointers, and you don't have an array of pointers. The solution would be making one, like this:

```
alpha *abc[5];
```

Then, you would be able to access any part of the array and set it to `NULL`

```
abc[2] = NULL;
```

Remember that, if you change it to pointers, you would need to allocate it (or make it point to something valid) and change the way you access each element of the `struct` (instead of `abc[1].x` it would be `abc[1]->x`)

Comment: Thanks @DavidBowling